# Need a Microsoft workflow to create response for request submitted by large audience

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

Need your support to share a Microsoft flow which will work from backend for the response submitted by different audience on the request basis.

Step 1 : Team will submit and response for 5 questionnaire created using Microsoft forms

Step 2 : Based upon the Team submitting the request, flow should move to Business team approval (which will refer to a set of approver name in Sharepoint list using vlookup)

Step 3 : Post Business team approval, flow should trigger mail to finance team approval (which will refer to a set of approver name in Sharepoint list using vlookup)

Step 4 : Flow will now move (post business and finance approval) requestion ID creation.

Step 5 : Post ID is created will move to next team

Note : a. In all these steps the requestor need to be notified with the current status, if rejected mail notification to be sent

b. Also want to know under which situation/condition we need to use/call variables or use/call conditions (please share explanation)

Flow Diagram FYR :-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziPhO.png)

Tried to automated but not sure where to call variables, where to use apply to all. so my flow is not completed.

Comment: Please be specific about the issue.

Comment: I need a flow for the diagram shared

Comment: I can't see the diagram (it's blocked on my network). Regardless, I suggest you implement each step of the flow one at a time and ask specific questions. For example, have you completed step 1?

Comment: Also what do you propose to build this in? I assumed this was a logic apps question but I think maybe Sharepoint or Power Automate might be better for you. I don't think this can be built in Outlook alone? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/all-assigned-must-approve

Comment: I am trying to build a flow using Power Automate, Microsoft Forms, SharePoint List & Outlook

Comment: I have created 5 question using Microsoft Form and roll out to my team for the input collection and share an Excel sheet to update their current requirement (this is part of my question form itself)

Comment: Post the inputs are received, I need to run and flow in backend, where it goes for two levels of approval. Where 1 level of approval I will know/get it from my Form Question itself. But 2nd level of approval details I will be adding it separately in an SharePoint List and based upon the department the request is received, flow need to get the data and send an reminder mail to concern approver

Comment: For above problem statement I need an flow, also want to know where to use variables, where to use get variable etc. I am totally blank and have zero knowledge on this

Comment: Went over the video you shared. I have created similar one already. But here my use case is I know approver 1 from the questionnaire shared with the audience. But for approver 2 I need to pull the date from SharePoint List based upon the audience response on which department they belong. so send me an flow for the same